# jQuery Ajax post is not running the Controller Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this jQuery-script:

```
var registrationModel = {
            SurName: document.getElementById("SurName").value,
            LastName: document.getElementById("LastName").value,
            Email: document.getElementById("Email").value,
            PhoneNumber: document.getElementById("PhoneNumber").value,
            Password: document.getElementById("Password").value,
            Name: document.getElementById("Name").value,
            Street: document.getElementById("Street").value,
            ZipCode: document.getElementById("ZipCode").value,
            City: document.getElementById("City").value,
            Country: document.getElementById("Country").value
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveRegisterDetailsToDb")',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(registrationModel),
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
```

And I have this Controller Action (user and company is set globally on the Controller):

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SaveRegisterDetailsToDb(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        //Skapa ApplicationUser i db

        user.UserName = model.Email;
        user.Email = model.Email;
        user.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;
        user.SurName = model.SurName;
        user.LastName = model.LastName;

        company.CompanyIdentity = model.CompanyIdentity;
        company.Name = model.Name;
        company.Street = model.Street;
        company.ZipCode = Convert.ToInt32(model.ZipCode);
        company.City = model.City;
        company.Country = model.Country;

        user.WorkPlaceId = company.CompanyIdentity;

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Customer");

            //Spara Company mot db.
            var db = new IdentityDb();

            db.Companies.Add(company);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View("Login");
    }
```

And this is my model:

```
  public class RegisterViewModel
{
    //Constructor
    public RegisterViewModel()
    {
        _companyIdentity = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    [Display(Name = "Användarnamn")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("SurName")]
    [Display(Name = "Förnamn")]
    public string SurName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("LastName")]
    [Display(Name = "Efternamn")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Phone]
    [Display(Name = "Telefonnummer")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "{0} måste vara minst {2} tecken långt. Försök igen!", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Lösenord")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Upprepa Lösenord")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Lösenorden stämmer inte. Försök igen!")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Adress")]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Postnummer")]
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Stad")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Land")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Namn på företag")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    private string _companyIdentity { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string CompanyIdentity { get { return _companyIdentity; } }
}
```

According to Fiddler, this is the post sent from the Ajax call:

```
POST http://localhost:54213/Account/SaveRegisterDetailsToDb HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:54213
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 

Firefox/35.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:54213/Account/Register
Content-Length: 235
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=i8CxmZxjAUoxA-u6T9Bw94g-Ysz1Z7WkjAq6HyYw3i69WJR4HUvFr1EGs5WtMDgQASl65ZwOOjkrZIfsFlIP1MqKmKuZzH6Tu2EPo56VFpk1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"model":{"SurName":"Göran","LastName":"Lassgård","Email":"gustavkaldner@yahoo.se","PhoneNumber":"543543","Password":"hej123","Name":"Gurras Kebab AB","Street":"Tobaksvägen 4","ZipCode":"25497","City":"Istanbul","Country":"Isreal"}}
```

The problem is that the jQuery Ajax post doesn´t run the "SaveRegisterDetailsToDb" like it´s suppose to.

I´ve set a breakpoint at the start of the Action, but it doesn´t hit it at all.

My simple question is why this Action never gets executed?

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Use Firebug/Chrome developer tools/Fiddler to look at what HTTP request is being generated.

Comment: Sorry if that sounds obvious, but is this action really defined in Account controller?

Comment: Is your jquery ajax call in view page only? Because Url helpers won't work in external javascript files. You may need to define global variables in view and access them in external javascript file.

Comment: @malkam His html helper is working fine, hence his fiddler output

Comment: does your method need to be async?  Could it not just be `public ActionResult`?

Comment: Just add these-  data: JSON.stringify(registrationModel),
            dataType: 'json',

Comment: Note it should be `data: JSON.stringify(registrationModel),` (although that does not explain why its not hitting the controller)

Comment: What happens when you try to call the controller with no input? (try to remove the model parameter from both the action signature and the ajax call)

Comment: Add the `error` function into your jQuery ajax call and log to console the error that is happening, that should give you a good idea of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for fast responses. The script is in the View only, not in an external script.
I use asp.net Identity and alot of the async functions otherwise I don´t need it to be async specific. I´m not sure though.

Comment: I´ve set a error into my Ajax-call and got back "no element found" on the post. So i suppose it doesn´t find the Action. Any ideas why?

Comment: It can be an issue with your parameter. If it works without a parameter ( after you removed your parameter from both the action signature and the ajax call) try to add   dataType: "json", to your ajax call and check that all of your properties spelled correctly.

Comment: Even without the parameters I get "no element found" response from the Ajax error. And yet the Action doesn´t run.

Comment: Try specifying the controller in the `@Url.Action`

Comment: Add your controller code. did you use [Authorize] attribute for the controller?

Comment: @User Thats it! After adding [AllowAnonymous] it works like a charm. Add your reply as a answer so I can mark it as right answer. Thanks everyone for your inputs.

Comment: You return a view to an ajax call... and the contentType is set to json. it might be it. Try to set it to text/html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [Authorize] on your controller, you should add the [AllowAnonymous]  attribute to your action to allow access to it.